# can anyone explain pathfinder algorithm used in Fpga routing?

Tags: routes, fpga, path-finding

How does the pathfinder algorithm work in FPGA routing? I have an oral exam on this topic next week... so can anyone explain the two iterations clearly with an example may be.

Comment: http://www.cecs.uci.edu/~papers/compendium94-03/papers/1995/fpga95/pdffiles/6a.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I understood after reading multiple research papers.

Algorithm runs in iterations

**first iteration:**

route every connection with minimum delay, even if there is
congestion

**Second iteration**

iterate as long as congestion exists

rip-up and re-route every net in the circuit

the cost of using a congested routing resource is increased from iteration to
iteration

at the end of an iteration, we have a complete routing (but maybe with
congestion); determine the delays and slacks of all connections